# FreeBSD: undeclared SYS_gettid

Tags: freebsd, compiling, c++

I am trying to install an R package (*mongolite*) on FreeBSD (FreeBSD 11.0-RELEASE-p9 amd64) and I am getting an error while compiling C++ source files.

The errors is the following: `error: 'SYS_gettid' undeclared`.

Any idea for how to go about this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SYS_xxxx` defines contain the numbers of system calls on Linux. They're used mostly when making raw system calls through the [`syscall(2)` wrapper](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) instead of the usual glibc wrapper functions. In the case of [`gettid()`, glibc doesn't contain a wrapper for the system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html), so it has to be called manually.

`gettid()` returns the thread ID on Linux, and [it appears it doesn't have a direct equivalent on FreeBSD](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2007-October/161218.html).

So, given the error, it seems the software you're trying to compile has a hard requirement for Linux, and the appropriate course of action would be to file a bug report to get it ported to FreeBSD. They should probably use `phtreads` or such.

Comment: Ok, so what can I do if I am trying to install an R package that in its C++ source uses raw syscall to SYS_gettid (line 53 in here: https://github.com/jeroen/mongolite/blob/master/src/bson/bson-context.c).

Is there any way to make `syscall (SYS_gettid);` valid on FreeBSD?

Comment: You are thinking about this backwards, possibly because this answer is focussing upon the Linux system call rather than on the compilation.  You need to modify your compilation and code to work on FreeBSD, not modify FreeBSD.  _There is conditional code in there to handle FreeBSD_, by the looks of things.  So you need to determine why your C++ compiler thinks that it is targetting Linux and is conditionally compiling the Linux code not the FreeBSD code.

Comment: @sztal, file a bug report or feature request about the software itself to get it ported to FreeBSD.

Comment: Yes, I already contacted the author and it fixed the problem, so it works on FreeBSD now.